# How to save CustomPaint file as a file (not image) with another format e.g ".psd", ".xml" or ".json" in flutter?

Tags: flutter, flutter-custompainter, flutter-canvas

i have a project that requires me to save all the scribbles that the user has drawn. i want to save it as a file that can later be opened and edited by the user again. does anyone have a solution to this problem? i have searched various forums and have not gotten an answer regarding this. thanks

The answer I got only gives a way to save the lines into a ".png" image where the image cannot be changed or edited anymore, my goal is that I want to create a special file so that the user can update the image file that he has done before.